# Error Handling in single threaded applications

Tags: spring-integration

In a single threaded Spring Integration, application where the entire pipleine is running within the same transaction, an error channel is not applicable. Instead, exceptions will be thrown back to the caller.

The way I am doing this is to define a service activator which is the first of a chain of components which handle an incoming message.

```
@ServiceActivator
public Message handleException(Message message) {
   try {
      return message;
   }
   catch (Throwable throwable){
      // HANDLE ERROR
   }
   return null;
}
```

Is this the correct approach, or is there a better strategy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No; that won't do anything at all; it will simply pass the message to the next element in the chain. If you don't need to handle the error in any way, and just want it thrown back to the caller, you need to do nothing. If the start of the flow is a gateway, the gateway will unwrap the cause from the `MessagingException`.

You can, of course, put an error-channel on the gateway and handle it there.

It's generally best to provide some more details about your flow (entry point etc), when asking these general questions.

Comment: Thanks Gary, should have been more specific. My entry point is a jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter (which uses a task executor). I know that in a single threaded application one can put an error channel in a Gateway, but can one be defined for the jdbc adapter in such a case? If not, how should errors be handled for the single thread/transaction scenario when the entry point is a jdbc adapter?

Comment: Yes, the `error-channel` goes on the poller (not the adapter) for polled endpoints. The poller triggers, hands off to a `TE` thread. If the poller is transactional, the transaction starts; if an exception is thrown the `ErrorMessage` is sent to the `error-channel` within the transaction, so the error flow can decide whether to catch and handle, in which case the transaction is committed, or if the error flow throws an exception, the transaction will be rolled back.